# Call to 'pkg-config --libs-only-l Qt5Core Qt5Network Qt5Widgets returned exit status 1

Tags: qt, npm, ubuntu-20.04, pkg-config

Environment Information:

- OS: **Ubuntu 20.04**
- Node JS version: **v9.6.1**
- npm version: **5.6.0**
- Qt - >Qt 5.9.9 (Custom Installation with including the options below)

  - Qt 5.9.9 -> Desktop gcc 64-bit
  - Qt 5.9.9 -> Qt Network Authorization
  - Qt 5.9.9 -> Qt Script (Deprecated)
- qtwebkit version: 5.212

I have installed Qt and along with QtWebkit plugin. The installation was successful and i am able to open the QtCreator gui.

I running and **npm install** command on node project that uses Qt. The command ends with following error:

```
Package 'Qt5WebKit' has no Description: field
gyp: Call to 'pkg-config --libs-only-l Qt5Core Qt5Network Qt5Widgets Qt5Gui Qt5WebKit Qt5WebKitWidgets Qt5Test' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/home/rando/.nvm/versions/node/v9.6.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:336:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:127:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.8.0-44-generic
gyp ERR! command "/home/rando/.nvm/versions/node/v9.6.1/bin/node" "/home/rando/.nvm/versions/node/v9.6.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/rando/Desktop/git/master-node/node/browser_engines/src/browsers/webkit
gyp ERR! node -v v9.6.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! company-browser-webkit@0.2.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the company-browser-webkit@0.2.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/rando/.npm/_logs/2021-03-02T16_42_43_655Z-debug.log
```

I have configured the environment variables as below:

```
export QT_HOME=/opt/Qt/5.9.9/gcc_64
export PATH=$PATH:$QT_HOME/bin
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:$QT_HOME/lib/pkgconfig;
```

I also try it without any luck to create sym links QtCore.pc, QtGUI.pc, and QtNetwork.pc for  Qt5Core.pc, Qt5GUI.pc, and Qt5Network.pc. This didn't solve my issue.

---

The execution of the following command returns :

`pkg-config --libs-only-l Qt5Core Qt5Network Qt5Widgets Qt5Gui Qt5WebKit Qt5WebKitWidgets Qt5Test`

output the message below:

```
Package 'Qt5WebKit' has no Description: field
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by going to the directory: `${QT_HOME}/gcc_64/lib/pkgconfig` directory and modified the files (Qt5WebKit.pc, Qt5WebKitWidgets.pc)by adding the description like below:

- Qt5WebKit.pc

```
Name: Qt5WebKit
Description: Qt Web Kit
Version: 5.212.0
Libs: -L/home/qt/work/install/lib -lQt5WebKit
Cflags: -I/home/qt/work/install/include/Qt5WebKit 
Requires: Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5Network
```

- Qt5WebKitWidgets.pc

```
Name: Qt5WebKitWidgets
Description: Qt Web Kit Widgets
Version: 5.212.0
Libs: -L/home/qt/work/install/lib -lQt5WebKitWidgets
Cflags: -I/home/qt/work/install/include/Qt5WebKitWidgets 
Requires:
```